# How to break a postfix php filter if it is false

Tags: php, filter, postfix-mta

I'm using postfix to recieve emails and send them through a php file for filtering.

in de postfix master.cf i use:

```
`smtp inet n - - - - smtpd -o content_filter=PHPFilter:dummy`
```

or

```
`pickup fifo n - - 60 1 pickup -o content_filter=PHPFilter:dummy`
```

but the question is: What if the email is passed trough the php file and no criteria is met?
is there a way to
    `break` or
    `exit`
 and let postfix resume?

For example the address: `info@domain.net` is an alias postfix should handle it.
but any digit email like `12345@domain.net` should be handled by the php filter.
but what if someone emails to a non existing email like `spam@domain.net`

As is: when using smtp (before queuing) the php filter is executed but when it's not a digit postfix isn't executed or at least not compared to the alias db.
when using the pickup (after queuing) postfix throws a 550 error (    Recipient address rejected: User unknown in virtual mailbox table
) when a digit email is send, because it doesn't exists in the alias db.

Comment: okey found out some thing. but the big issue remains.
exit(67) tells postfix to reply sender with "user unknown".
exit(0) tells postfix the filter has accepted the email.
but what tells postfix to process the message and maildrop?
i have tried to resend it with sendmail into postfix but this turns into an infinite loop (about 48 times).

Comment: okey figured out some more..
if an email is not accepted bij the filter (doesn't meet the requirements) it needs to be reinserted into postfix, using sendmail (local deliverer not through SMTP because than it will go trough the filter again, hense the 48 loop mentioned above.)

now the question remains how to resend the original message in PHP?
using mail() it will rewrite the headers and such..
is there a way to send raw data using PHP and sendmail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've managed to do everything just fine except for the PHP script itself. Here's how I would do it:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php

$content = stream_get_contents(STDIN);

//Here you decide if you want to let the email pass through or not
$pass_through = true;
$sendmail_return_value = 69;

if ($pass_through) {
    unset($argv[0]);
    $sendmail = '/usr/sbin/sendmail -G -i ' . implode(' ', $argv);
    $handle = popen($sendmail, 'w');
    fwrite($handle, $content);
    $sendmail_return_value = pclose($handle);
}

exit($sendmail_return_value);
```

Comment: makes sense to do it like you suggested.
until now i've destructide the entire message and constructed it again using PEAR. but it caused a lot of unforeseen problems / challenges.
just passing it through would solve it.

Comment: for anybody else reading this "blog".
$args = $_SERVER['argv']
passed bij postfix master.cf (see post below)
and is needed bij sendmail for the -t argument.

Answer (score 1):

Alright figured it out. here is the description for others like me who couldn't get this figured out. it still isn't pretty (no raw data but instead a new mail is inserted into postfix.)
first as mentioned above in the master.cf (postfix) put/replace:

`smtp inet n - - - - smtpd -o content_filter=PHPFilter:dummy`

and

```
PHPFilter unix  -   n   n   -   10  pipe
  flags=F user=www-data null_sender=
  argv=/var/secure/postfix.php -f ${sender} -- ${recipient}
```

to accept the numeric email addresses i've created a virtual_mailbox_maps to check the database if the number is valid/present.

so far postfix. now the postfix.php filter file.
first read the incomming email:

```
    if($fd = @fopen("php://stdin", "r")) {
        while (!feof($fd)) {
            $this->email .= fread($fd, 1024);
        }
        fclose($fd);
        return true;
    }
```

this can be decoded with PEAR::Mail_mimedecode to get all the variables needed
those can be processed (filtered) and manipulated as needed.
if the postfix.php filter meets the required parameters of the filter it should return with exit(0) to let postfix know everything is handled no further action required.

if the email isn't meeting the requirements or if it is a local mailbox the email schould be reinserted into postfix using a local port (so don't use PEAR::mail->send('smtp'))
instead use PEAR::Mail->send('sendmail') to insert it back into postfix.
this requires you to build a new email from the ground up. using the variables provided by PEAR::Mail_mimedecode.

```
$headers = array(
    'From' => $this->headers['from'],
    'To' => $this->headers['to'],
    'Subject' => $this->headers['subject'],
    'Date' => $this->headers['date']
    );
```

Hope this helps anybody. i provide the process here. off course it needs refining as you please and for safety.
if someone has any comment on this process please provide them. i would love to hear if there are any safety issues or better approach to doing this.

Comment: i think i need to use php's STDOUT and STDERR to process the pipe from postfix and return the original email to the queue. instead of PEAR/sendmail.  
but i can't seem to find any info on this. does anybody have an example for me?